# How can I add picture for a contact?

Tags: android, ios, smartface.io

I want to add a contact to mobile device via addContact (http://docs.smartface.io/?topic=html/M_Device_Contacts_addContact.htm) method. I tried to add person picture. But i can't see image parameter. How can i add contact picture in Smartface Platform?

Comment: Please show us what you tried, and try to explain what you expected to happen and how you think it did not.

Comment: Do you have any idea about Smartface Platform or knowledge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Device.addContact() method takes 6 parameters which are described in the docs and guides. Contacts can not be added with a photo , however it will be a good enhancement.

http://docs.smartface.io/?topic=html/M_Device_Contacts_addContact.htm

http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/device/device-contacts/

Here is a sample usage;

```
Device.Contacts.addContact({
    firstName:"Smartface",
    lastName:"AppStudio",
    phoneNumber:"555555555",
    email:"info@smartface.io",
    url:"http://www.smartface.io",
    address:"Palo Alto",    
    onSuccess:function(){
        alert("contact is added.");},
    onError:function(){
    alert("An Error occured.");}});
```